# Javascript Decrease Global variable when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

Im very new to javascript and i need some help.
I want to make a button that collects wood/stone and when it gets pressed i want it to decrease the stamina by 1.I made a code but it doesnt work.

```
<div class="menu">
<p class="ing">Stamina:<p id="stamina">20</p></p>
 <button onclick="collect_wood()" class="button">Collect Wood</button><p class="ing">Wood:<p id="wood">0</p> </p>
<button onclick="collect_stone(stamina)" class="button2">Collect Stone</button><p class="ing2">Stone:<p id="stone">0</p> </p>

</div>


<script>
wood=0;
stone=0;
stamina=20;
function collect_wood() {
    stamina = stamina - 1;
    wood=wood+1;
    document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
}
function collect_stone(stamina) {
    stamina = stamina - 1;
    stone=stone+1;
    document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stone;
}



document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;


</script>
```

Comment: You aren't updating the `stamina` box when the click events fire, and you are using a local variable in `collect_stone`.

Comment: added demo for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stamina` variable is being updated on click of `wood` count  but on `stone` count you are taking a parameter that is creating problem. Removing that will work.

And you should update `innerHTML` of stamina after each click.

Like bellow

```
function collect_wood() {
    stamina = stamina - 1;
    wood=wood+1;
    document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
    document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
}

function collect_stone() {
    stamina = stamina - 1;
    stone=stone+1;
    document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stone;
    document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
}
```

Don't pass the parameter to `collect_stone` function

```
<button onclick="collect_stone()" class="button2">Collect Stone</button>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/qvwpp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
wood=wood+1;
```

use this:

```
window.wood=window.wood+1;
```

or this

```
window.wood+=1;
```

by attaching it to the window object - it makes it global.

See [here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable).

Answer (score 0):

You are 90% there! It looks like you are doing everything right but you are not updating the stamina dom object except at the initial run.  You just need to move updating the innterHTML of the stamina object inside your functions.  SO something like this:

`

```
wood=0;
stone=0;
stamina=20;
function collect_wood() {
    stamina = stamina - 1;
    wood=wood+1;
    document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
    //Update each time!
    document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
}
function collect_stone(stamina) {
    stamina = stamina - 1;
    stone=stone+1;
    document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stone;
    //Update each time!
    document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
}
```

`

Good Luck and welcome to the world of html and javascript!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure that you're referencing everything correctly. Use console.log in your functions to make sure they're being fired, etc.

```
<div class="menu">
    <p class="ing">Stamina:
        <p id="stamina">20</p>
    </p>
    <button onclick="collect_wood()" class="button">Collect Wood</button>
    <p class="ing">Wood:
        <p id="wood">0</p>
    </p>
    <button onclick="collect_stone()" class="button2">Collect Stone</button>
    <p class="ing2">Stone:
        <p id="stone">0</p>
    </p>
</div>
<script>
    wood = 0;
    stone = 0;
    stamina = 20;

    function collect_wood() {

        stamina--;
        wood++;
        document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;

        update_stamina();
    }

    function collect_stone() {
        stamina--;
        stone++;
        document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stone;

        update_stamina();
    }

    function update_stamina() {
        document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, but it calls once at the time of page loading.
Why can't you update the 'stamina' variable value inside the functions?

```
function collect_stone(stamina) {

    //alert(stamina);
    stamina = stamina - 1;
    stone=stone+1;
    document.getElementById("stone").innerHTML = stone;
}
```